# How to extract an array that has a given structure and which's key => value matches a given value of an mutlidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array consisting of many other arrays, which might also consist of other arrays. Its basically like a navigation hierarchy, one menu link can be a menu with sub menus and so on.

The structure of `$mainarray` is like this:

```
'childarray1' => array(
    'link' => array(
        ..
        'mykey' => 'valueofinterest'
    ),
    'below' => array() of childarrays

),
'childarray2' => array(
    'link' => array(
        ..
        'mykey' => 'somevalue'
    )

),
'childarray3' => array(
    'link' => array(
        ..
        'mykey' => 'someothervalue'
    ),
    'below' => array() of childarrays

)
```

Each `childarray` can have 2 direct child `keys`, `'links'` and optionally `'below'`. Within `links` there is always a `key 'mykey'`, which is the only key that I need to check. If a child array has `['links']['mykey'] == 'valueofinterest'`, **I'd like to have this element returned**, like `$sub = $mainarray['child1']['below']['child11']['below']['childofinterest']`.
`'below'` means that the childarray has childs itself which can also have below arrays (sub menu..).

My hude problem is that the childarray I try to find can be in any other childarrays'S `'below'` key, I dont know the depth (its not too deep, though it can vary). I've tried to mess with foreach loops and while loops and combining those, I just cant figure it out how to get the child array. I want to do it like this:

```
$value = 'xxx';

$sub = return_sub_menu($value);

function return_sub_menu($value) {
    $array = $mainarray();
    $sub = array();

    // find the child array which's ['link']['mykey'] == $value;

    // $sub is now something like:
    // 'childarray321' => array(
    //  'link' => array(
    //      ..
    //      'mykey' => 'xxx'
    //  ),
    //  'below' => array() of childarrays which i NEEED :)
    // 
    // )
    return $sub;
}
```

I've tried to walk recursively but cant figure out how to return the element :(

Comment: have you tried [array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#96564)

Comment: no worries it will work. instead of direct function use anonymous function

Comment: can you post an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function recursiveSearch($array, $value){
  foreach($array as $sub){
    if ($sub['link']['mykey'] == $value)
      return $sub ;

    if (!empty($sub['below'])){
        $returned = recursiveSearch($sub['below'], $value);
        if ($returned !== null)
            return $returned ;
    }
  }

    return null ;
}

$sub = recursiveSearch($array, "valueofinterest"); 
//Returns array with ['link']['mykey'] == $value ;
var_dump($sub);
```

**UPDATE V2**

Fixed the function, so it works now

Comment: wouldnt this fail when like the first child array has a below key, but the very next childarray would have been the array of interest?

Comment: youre the only person that understood that i am searching for the value, not the key :D thanks for your help so far

Comment: Yeah, you were right. I updated the function, it does not fail now.

Comment: i get null returned because once a childarray has a below key, all te other siblings are not being considered

Comment: so i guess one should FIRST look trhough all children ($array as $sub), and if not found, create a new array of the below arrays and recall the function on those

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
if (array_key_exists('keyvalue', $array)) {
    $subarray = $array['keyvalue'];
    return $subarray;
}
```

It will return sub array

Comment: how does this help me? The key always exists, in every child array. I need to find the childarray whichs' key, for instance "foobar" equals a given string, like if ['foobar'] = $value

Answer (score 0):

here it is.

```
$finalarray = array_map(create_function('$yourarray', 'return $yourarray["arrayindex"];'), $actualarray );
```

Comment: does not really work, i am not trying to test of the key exists, it always does